# ASP.NET - Best practice for setting value of SqlDataSource Parameter from a QueryString value @ Page Load?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Let's say we have a value coming in through the URL of a page. Example: www.test.com/page.aspx?&Key=Val. Val is retrievable through Request.Querystring("Key").

**Is there an accepted best practice for assigning a QueryString Value to a parameter of a SqlDataSource defined on an ASPX page?**

Options that I know of:

1. Do not include parameters in the ASPX file. Add them directly through the codebehind -- and assign Param.DefaultValue upon adding.
2. Set Param.DefaultValue in the page load (Codeblock 2)

Both of these use DefaultValue, a property that clearly was not intended to be used in this manner. Do the ASP.NET overlords have a recommended method in mind for achieving this common task?

**Codeblock 1**

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="StoreID" Type="String" DefaultValue="-1" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

**Codeblock 2:**

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SD1.SelectParameters("StoreID").DefaultValue = Request.QueryString("StoreID")
 End Sub
```

Comment: I understand other questions have covered various ways to achieve this task. This question is more along the lines of how the ASP.NET team intended this task to be performed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best handled using the DataSource events directly, not the PageLoad events.

To set the QueryString in the Select, add this to your datasource:

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="StoreID" QueryStringField="StoreID" Type="Int64" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

This tells the DataSource Select to look for "?StoreID=x" in the QueryString and set StoreID to 'x' from the URL as you mentioned.

To set a default value for StoreID, hook into the DataSource Selecting Event like this:

```
Protected Sub SD1DataSource_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SD1DataSource.Selecting
    If e.Command.Parameters("@StoreID").Value Is Nothing Then
        e.Command.Parameters("@StoreID").Value = 155
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: modified to use your variable names.

Comment: Wow, had no idea that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, we had this issue a lot.  Let me know if you need help hooking it all in.

Answer (score 1):

I did sometimes ago it with object datasource and i didn't add default value to Page_Load or ASPx.

```
public class QueryStringKey<T>
{
    public static implicit operator QueryStringKey<T>(string key)
    {
        return new QueryStringKey<T> { Key = key };
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasValue == false)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(Key);
            }

            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(_valueString);
            }
            catch
            {
                return (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_valueString);
        }
    }

    private string _valueString
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[Key];
        }
    }
}

public class QueryStringKeys
{
    public static QueryStringKey<int> StoreId = "StoreId";
}

    protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (QueryStringKeys.StoredId.HasValue)
            e.InputParameters["StoreId"] = QueryStringKeys.StoreId.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I would have guessed that SqlDataDource Selectparameters would allow this, but they do not. Unable to convert string to Parameter. For now, I just adjust the DefaultValue property, but it feels wrong.

Comment: I checked it out now. parameter values able to change when selecting event fire but i think its directly accessing SqlCommand; 
e.Command.Parameters["@StoreId"].Value = QueryStringKeys.StoreId.Value;

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a Value property on the parameter, only a defaultValue. Fortunately Jamon informed me about the QueryStringParameter that seems to have been designed specifically for this purpose.